# Where can I find a Ubuntu 12.04 image for ARM v6?

Tags: arm, raspberrypi

I would like to run Ubuntu 12.04 for use with Ubuntu TV I would prefer this to be a ARM PC can I use a Raspberry Pi? If so how do I set it up? I have a Model B rev.2 but if it won't work then what is a recommended to use as a ARM V6 or later system?

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/Server

Comment: In general Ubuntu is only compiled for ARMv7 and beyond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM

in section "ARM Processor" is text with small font "Limited support for earlier instruction sets (ARMv5t, ARMv6) was available in early releases of the ARM port (jaunty, karmic)."

http://elinux.org/RPi_Distributions#Ubuntu

it seems, that you have no luck with raspeberry pi 1, i recomend you to use PI 2

Comment: Use of a Raspberry Pi 2 doesn't really improve the situation in running 12.04.  Snappy [isn't even supported fully](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/#snappy-raspi2) though it is available for it.  Ubuntu MATE [is available](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/) for the Raspberry Pi 2 but is in version 15.04 and not 12.04 as the question asks.